# С помощью чего можно написать бота для движения мышки и нажимания на кнопку?

Tags: c#, c++, python

Появилась необходимость написания бота для программы. Пробовал писать на pyautogui, но увы не получилось ввиду невозможности нажимания кнопок в нужной мне программе ( я так и не понял почему, но мышка движется как нужно, но кнопки в программе отказывается нажимать.) С помощью чего можно это еще реализовать? Может есть сервис, или программа, или библиотека, язык не важен. Спасибо.
`

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep
##
# пауза и досрочное прекращениe
pyautogui.PAUSE = 1
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
## 
# Разрешение
sleep (1)
pyautogui.size()
pyautogui.position()
pyautogui.moveTo(400, 1050 )
## Кликнуть по правой кнопке
pyautogui.click()
##
pyautogui.moveTo(450, 1050 )
## Кликнуть по правой кнопке трижды
pyautogui.tripleClick()
##`
```

Comment: Реализовать нажатие кнопок можно с помощью всего. Почему кнопка не нажимается? Исходники в студию! Какая операционная система?

Comment: если надо кликер, то уже существуют готовые решения

Comment: @virvaldium винда 10 домашняя, в питоне прописывал pyautogui.click (450, 300), предворительно установил pyautogui, на рабочем столе в браузере все работает, но когда захожу в программу где должен работать бот, вообще отказывается работать. И стоит отметить, что когда открыто приложение и скрыта командная строка (при выполнение скрипта) то вообще ничего не происходит, но когда я открываю командную строку он начинает работать, но опять же не нажимая кнопки.

Comment: @goldstar_labs а можно пример? И желательно бесплатные, или хотя бы в меру стоящие.

Comment: @virvaldium я изменил вопрос, теперь там есть код который должен работать

Comment: https://gs-auto-clicker.ru.uptodown.com/windows https://www.autohotkey.com/ ...

Comment: Я не знаком с этой библиотекой если честно. Но вы уверены, что 'pyautogui.click()' это клик правой кнопкой? Может он кликает, но левой кнопкой? И еще, глупый вопрос конечно, но вы уверены, что курсов находится точно над кнопкой?

Comment: судя по документации, click() делает все таки нажатие левой кнопкой. И еще попробуйте 'pyautogui.click(x=moveToX, y=moveToY, clicks=num_of_clicks, interval=secs_between_clicks, button='left')' dspsdfnm 'njn vtnj c gfhfvtnhfvb

Comment: @virvaldium загвоздка в том что любой скрипт и даже программный автокликер отказывается работать в нужной мне программе

Answer (score 0):

winetricks используют для подобных целей autohotkey

Comment: А разве эта программа способна двигать курсор мышки?

Comment: @Tryr https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseMove.htm

Comment: А есть возможность нажимать кнопки мышки? Я не смог найти...